# get or simulate NSLocale for current user

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want my App to be used from few iTunes stores. I read [NSLocale Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and they are talking about "current user". So, who is "current user"? Is it user which has downloaded app?

1) is it possible to get NSLocale depending on current appleID country or iTunes store country from which my App was downloaded?

2) is it possible to simulate NSLocale to test my App?

Comment: What about a user who has appleID created from country XYZ, and now using it from country ABC?

Comment: i want to get XYZ country anywhere.

Comment: iOS is not a multi-user system, so I don't understand the issue.

Comment: Add an option to your app so that the user can explicitly set the locale.

Comment: user with AppleID bound with country XYZ downloaded app. And i want to get XYZ and locale. Is it possible to automatically get locale?

Comment: i found how to simulate locales. You need to download ios-sim-locale sript.
But i don't understand who is "current user"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS, there is no such thing as a "current user". The reference to "current user" in the `NSLocale` docs is probably a hold over from the OS X docs.

In iOS, run the Settings app and go to General, then International. The "Region Format" and the "Language" settings define what you get back in iOS for `[NSLocale currentLocale]`.

There is no way, in iOS, for a third party app to obtain any sort of appleID or information about a specific iTunes store.

To directly answer your two questions:

1) No, you have no access to this information

2) Yes, run the Settings app and change the Language and/or Region Format settings. This will affect the `NSLocale` you obtain in your app.

Comment: Changing the region and language in the iOS 7.0 simulator settings doesn't change the result of [NSLocale currentLocale] - it always returns a country code of "US" and currency code of "USD". It worked in the 6.1 simulator.

Comment: Very odd, restarting the simulator didn't help, but when I switched to 6.1 and back to 7.0.3, it now works fine. At this point, I'm thinking it was caused by an evil spirit... :D

Answer (score 1):

Mates, i found a solution to get user's (Apple ID, iTunes store) locale! You can get locale from SKProduct.

```
if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
{
   [self requestProductData];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark In-App Purchase Delegate Methods

- (void)requestProductData
{
    NSLog(@"IN-APP:requestProductData");
    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:<your in-app identifier>]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *myProduct = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:response.products];
    if ([myProduct count]>0)
    {
        SKProduct *product = [myProduct objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Price: %.2f",product.price.floatValue);
        NSLog(@"Price Locale: %@",product.priceLocale.localeIdentifier);
        NSLog(@"Product Identifier: %@",product.productIdentifier);
        NSLog(@"IN-APP:array count: %i", [myProduct count]);
        [request autorelease];
    }
    [myProduct release];
    myProduct = nil;
}
```